# I need to write utest in Python for below method

Tags: python, mocking, utest

Function prototype :

```
def sample_test(self, param1, param2, optional_param1=False, optional_param2=False, 
            optional_param3={}):
    if optional_param2:
       print("In param2")
    if optional_param3:
       print("In param3")
```

Now if I call the method as sample_test(param1, param2, False, {"key": "val"}) In param2 gets printed .`optional_param2` is assigned with dict and the test is executed wrongly as `optional_param2` is considered as `True`. I want to write utest for the same so that these errors are caught beforehand.. I want to write utest for the method so that these type of errors are caught and function is executed efficiently .

Answer (score 0):

You can assign inputs directly, like

```
def function(v1=0,v2=1):
    return (v1,v2)
print(function(v2=7))
>>(0,7)
```

Plugging this into your code might look like:

```
sample_test(param1, param2, False, optional_param3={"key":"val"})
```

in which optional_param2 would default to False while optional_param3 receives the correct dictionary.